# Do sections of a vector bundle over manifold form a Hilbert space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ denote a real (or complex) vector bundle of rank $r$ with a Riemannian (or Hermitean) fibre metric $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, over a smooth oriented manifold $M$ and let $\Gamma(E)$ denote the vector space of smooth sections of $E$. Fix a volume form $\omega$ of $M$, and for sections $f,g\in \Gamma(E)$ we set
$$\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2}=\int_M \langle f, g\rangle\omega $$
then is the space
$$L^2(E)=\{f\in\Gamma:\langle f,f\rangle_{L^2}<\infty\}$$
a Hilbert space with respect to $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$? If not, what is an assumption for the $M$ for which it holds?

Comment: Have you tried yourself to verify the assumptions needed?

Comment: @Deane First I think it is compact but there is no reason.

Comment: @Deane Originally, does it hold for general manifolds?

Comment: You forgot completeness. if $M=\bf R$ and $E$ is the trivial line bundle, the space of $C^{\infty}$ function is not a Hilbert space, but only pre-hilbertian. Just replace your definition by the set of $L^2$ section ie section such that the square of there norm is $L^1$.

Comment: Don’t guess. Check the definition rigorously step by step.